# How to get current time ,date and timezoneinfo from windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing an app and I want to get the current time, date and time zone info from my Windows Phone 8.1.

I have been looking over the internet but I can't find any example.

Help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

`Date.Now` gives you current date/time, and [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bb383167.aspx) gives you a `TimeZoneInfo` object that represents the local time zone.